# JSonConverter how to make generic deserialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json.net, deserialization

I have been able to do a custom Converter that transforms to a list of interfaces.

Here my custom converter:

```
public class InvoiceDetailConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        //assume we can convert to anything for now
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        List<InvoiceDetail> data = serializer.Deserialize<List<InvoiceDetail>>(reader);

        // now loop to make the proper list
        List<IInvoiceDetail> result = new List<IInvoiceDetail>();
        foreach (IInvoiceDetail d in data) {
            result.Add(d);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        //use the default serialization - it works fine
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

What I would like is to make this generic like

```
public class InvoiceDetailConverter <TConcrete, TInterface> : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        //assume we can convert to anything for now
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        List<TConcrete> data = serializer.Deserialize<List<TConcrete>>(reader);

        // now loop to make the proper list
        List<TInterface> result = new List<TInterface>();
        foreach (TInterface d in data) {
            result.Add(d);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        //use the default serialization - it works fine
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

At the End in my object it will be used like this:

```
public class test{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InvoiceDetailConverter<InvoiceDetail, IInvoiceDetail>))]
    public List<IInvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to convert like this, as the above code won't compile. I'm using .NET Core.

Comment: Why not use an existing tool like Newtonsoft's JSON.NET? What problem are you attempting to solve that requires you make custom code?

Comment: Hi, this is a custom converter that Newtonsoft's JSON.NET will used thru attribute.

basiquely my main object as a List<IInvoiceDetail> which need to be deserialize. im trying to make it generic so that i can used it for other list afterward

Comment: Then what error are you getting? What is it you're trying to do? Looking at your first example, it looks like you're trying to tell it what concrete class to convert it to, but actually return it as the interface instead? Did you try telling JSON.NET to convert it to your concrete type, but have your variable as a collection of the interface?

Comment: Basiquely here what im trying:
this will work: 
     List<InvoiceDetail> data = serializer.Deserialize<List<InvoiceDetail>>(reader);

            // now loop to make the proper list
            List<IInvoiceDetail> result = new List<IInvoiceDetail>();
            foreach (IInvoiceDetail d in data) {
                result.Add(d);
            }
but doing it with generic (called TConcrete and TInterface) won't work.

What im trying to achieve is to make my converter generic so that i will be able to used it for any list that contain a list of interface insead of a list of concrete Obj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're almost there, just specify dependency between `TConcrete` and `TInterface`:

```
public class InvoiceDetailConverter<TConcrete, TInterface> : JsonConverter
    where TConcrete : TInterface    // <------------------------------------------ add this
{
    // ..........
}
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yipij0) you can find a demo of successful deserialization using the generic converter class for the following object:

```
public class test
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(InvoiceDetailConverter<InvoiceDetail, IInvoiceDetail>))]
    public List<IInvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetail { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(InvoiceDetailConverter<VatDetail, IVatDetail>))]
    public List<IVatDetail> VatDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank's, this is waht i was missing, now it work like a charm!

Comment: Nice work. I got pulled into something at work, and didn't have a chance to write this up.